# Show and hide buttons as soon as counters increases or decreases?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

It goes like this, I have a numericUpDown which has a max value of 4. I want to make it so if the value is 1 only one button appears, if value is 2, two buttons appears, etc. How can I manage to do this in code ? I am using a timer and on every tick it checks if the value of the numericUpDown changes and if its changed it adds buttons, but how can I do the opposite thing, if value decreases, remove buttons? For example if I  have the value of 4 and I already have 4 buttons appeared if I decrease with ONE, only one button should go away. How can I do this ?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)
        {
            metroComboBox3.Show();
        }
        else if (numericUpDown1.Value == 2)
        {
            metroComboBox4.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say numericUpDown decreases by one and one button goes away do you mean: if numericUpDown decreases from 4 to 3 that button4 goes away or button1 goes away?

Comment: Instead of a Timer, use the [NumericUpDown.ValueChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it with a timer then this is the way to go:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var buttons = new [] { button1, button2, button3, button4, };
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].Visible = numericUpDown1.Value - 1 >= i
    }
}
```

But I would use the `numericUpDown1.ValueChanged` event and do this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var buttons = new [] { button1, button2, button3, button4, };
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].Visible = numericUpDown1.Value - 1 >= i
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the question, there is zero reason to use a timer to check the value of the numeric up/down. I realize it is included for completeness, but I'd hate to see a younger dev see this answer and think using a timer is an appropriate path forward.

Comment: @MetroSmurf - I couldn't agree more. I did try to to convey that message with the "If you have to" and "But I would use" phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a double click on you numericUpDown in design, you dont need a timer.

You will get `private void  numericUpDown1_ValueChanged`

Afther that your code should look like this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)
            {
                metroComboBox3.Show();
            }
            else if (numericUpDown1.Value == 2)
            {
                metroComboBox4.Show();
            }
        }
```